# How to Regex split time string

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I have a time string `var time = "12:30:49PM"`

I want to separate the hour, min, sec and AM/PM from that string.

Browsing stackoverflow I was able to find the following regex that split hour, min and Am/pm, but I am very bad at regex so I cant work out how to do the sec.

```
 var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
 var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
 var AMPM = time.match(/([AaPp][Mm])$/)[1];
```

how to get the second via regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you would simply do something like:

```js
var time = "12:30:49PM";   
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/([AaPp][Mm])$/)[1];
var seconds = Number(time.match(/:(\d+):(\d+)/)[2]);
console.log(hours, ":", minutes, ":", seconds, AMPM);
```

However, it'd be more effecient to get everything in one call:

```js
var time = "12:30:49AM";
var matches = time.match(/^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)([AP]M)$/i);
var hours = matches[1];
var minutes = matches[2];
var seconds = matches[3];
var AMPM = matches[4];
console.log(hours, ":", minutes, ":", seconds, AMPM);
```

Comment: If anyone wants to use this with toLocaleTimeString, you can do the following:

new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { timeZone }).match(/(\d+):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM)/i)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of regex with ES6 array destructuring:

```js
const time = "12:30:49PM"
const [hour, min, sec, period] = time.match(/\d+|\w+/g);

console.log(hour, min, sec, period);
```

Comment: That's a nive way :)

Comment: This is lovely!

Comment: I like your approach as well, and it's likely what I'd do too. The one problem is the regex is a bit too loose, so it might not always work as expected and you wouldn't have an easy way to tell because it'd probably just go with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like so:

```js
var time = "12:30:49PM"
var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
var sec = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)\D+$/)[1]);
var AMPM = time.match(/([ap]m)$/i)[1];
console.log(hours);
console.log(minutes);
console.log(sec);
console.log(AMPM);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split on colon and the (P\A)M part

```js
var time  = "12:30:49PM";
var parts = time.split(/:|(\DM)/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sec = Number(time.match(/:([0-9][0-9])/ig)[1].replace(":",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about!:

```
console.log(DateTimeFormat(new Date(), '`The Year is ${y} DateTime is: ${m}/${d}/${y} Time is: ${h}:${M}:${s}   `'))

function DateTimeFormat(dt, fmt)
{
    [y, m, d, h, M, s, ms] =  new 
    Date(dt).toLocaleString('UTC').match(/\d+/g)
    return eval(fmt)
}
```